# How does the `gcloud` CLI use OAuth2 to authenticate a user?

Tags: python, go, google-cloud-platform, oauth, gcloud

I'm trying to mimic the flow for authenticating with GCP using the `gcloud` CLI in a Go project. In this case, I can't just shell out to `gcloud` using the `os` package because I have to assume it's not installed on the system. I also need to avoid having the user go in and set an OAuth2 `client_id` and `client_secret` in the developer console since the `gcloud` CLI doesn't seem to require it.

I was trying to look through the Python code for `gcloud` and I can sort of see what it's doing but it's a bit difficult to follow since I'm not super experienced in Python and it seems like there are many layers of abstraction in the authentication code that are a bit hard to break through.

I can see the GCP URLs (the ones that you open in the browser when doing `gcloud auth login`) have a `client_id` but they don't have a `client_secret`. They also look like they do PKCE but I'm not super familiar with how that works. I also can't figure out exactly where they get the `client_id` from. If it's somehow bundled with the `gcloud` CLI I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Google publishes examples on how to use OAuth. I have written several articles including one that shows how to use the **curl** CLI. The process is fairly easy. I do not recommend trying to figure out how the **gcloud** CLI does it as it uses special account credentials and implements items you do not need. Or at least wait until you understand how to do everything using OAuth.

Comment: This may help https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication or possibly just confuse you more.

Comment: @JohnHanley I understand how OAuth works because I've integrated applications with OAuth before, even with GCP's own OAuth provider. What I'm trying to understand is specifically how I can follow the OAuth flow without having a pre-created client ID and secret like the `gcloud` CLI does it.

Comment: @Hugo - use the **gcloud** command flag `--log-http`. The CLI will print each HTTP request. Some details are masked, but those details will help you know where in the source code to look. Note: I am not sure what Google's security scanners will do if you start using Google credentials.

Comment: @JohnHanley Ahh thanks for the tip I'll do that.